# Griffiths Quantum Mechanics - How can magnetic quantum number $m$ possibly be negative?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals, textbook-erratum, spherical-harmonics

I apologize if this is already somewhere on this site, I searched with relevant keywords but could find nothing. This is from David Griffiths' Introduction to QM.

In section 4.1.2 (Angular Equation), where Griffiths solves the Schrodinger Equation using separation of variables in spherical coordinates, he says the following is the Rodrigues formula:
$$
P_l^m(x) = (-1)^m (1-x^2)^{m/2}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^mP_l(x)
$$
Then, he says that $l$ is a non-negative integer because the Legendre polynomials $P_l$ are only defined for $l \geq 0$. This makes sense to me.

Then he says something I don't get at all:
He says if $m > l$, then $P^m_l = 0$, so there are $2l + 1$ possible values of $m$. $l = 0, 1, 2, ...$, and $m = -l, -l + 1, \ldots, 0, \ldots, l$. I don't get this at all! How can $m$ be negative? $(\frac{d}{dx})^m$ makes no sense if $m$ is negative, so $P^m_l$ is undefined!!!

Can someone help me out, is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: I think he’s being sloppy or you’re misunderstanding him. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials) says that equation holds for $m\ge 0$ and shows how it can be extended to negative $m$ using the real Rodrigues formula.

Comment: @G.Smith You are right, the Rodrigues formula is for the Legendre polynomials, not associated Legendre functions! My bad!

Answer (score 1):

In my copy of Griffiths (2nd edition, page 136, equation [4.27]), the definition of the associated Legendre polynomials is

$$P^m_l(x) = (1-x^2)^{|m|/2} \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{|m|} P_l(x)$$

This is not the Rodrigues formula (equation [4.28]), which says that the $l^{th}$ Legendre polynomial is
$$P_l(x) = \frac{1}{2^l l!} \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^l (x^2-l)^l$$

Comment: Okay. So $m > l$ would imply that we have more than $2l$ derivatives, so the $(x^2-1)^l$ term would become zero, so we require $m \leq l$. And then so if $m$ is negative, you're simply taking less than $l$ derivatives but that means that $m \geq -l$, so the whole thing is still well defined! Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: And thus we get $m = -l, -l + 1, \ldots, 0, 1, \ldots, l - 1, l$

Comment: Yes, that’s right.